# UIPicker not getting data

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

having trouble with a double component uipicker, everything shows up and it fills with the right data, but when you click the DONE button, it defaults to row 0, dont know what im doing wrong or if im missing something
any help will be appreciated

http://jptarry.com/iPhoneTest/picker.zip

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIPicker shows up but not saving data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108881/uipicker-shows-up-but-not-saving-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the connection from doublePicker to the actual UIPickerView.

Open Interfacebuilder and connect the doublePicker outlet of the File Owner with the PickerView.

You should have read the comment by Chiefly Izzy.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to bind picker in XIB with file owner..